# Find out/Tracking down why LuaLaTeX loads a certain font

Tags: fonts, luatex

I have switched to LuaLaTeX for my project and I am using unicode-math and libertinus. If I examine the resulting PDF, I see that the two fonts CMBX8 and CMBXTI10 are still partially included as Type-1 fonts. They only contain the latin lowercase letters "r", "u" and "p".

(The other fonts are all included as CID Typ 0C and are from the Libertinus family as expected.)

How can I find out, why and where LuaLaTeX includes these fonts and for what purpose?

I guess, that there are some glyphs "r", "u" and "p" from the Computer Modern font in my final PDF, but that is not supposed to happen.

Comment: you can try `\usepackage[loading]{tracefnt}`  and then look in the log.

Comment: or `\showoutput` will show the fonts used for every letter in the document

Comment: Are you using `\bf` in math mode somewhere?  That will use CMBX.

Comment: @HenriMenke I believe you might be right. However, it seems to happen in a package (`ntheorem`) and I do not know how to fix it. I posted a follow up question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528861