# LuaLaTeX, ntheorem, unicode-math and Libertinus: Math in theorem header loads Computer Modern

Tags: luatex, unicode-math, ntheorem, boldmath, libertinus

Consider this MWE and compile it with LuaLaTex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertinus}
\usepackage{ntheorem}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newcommand*{\hybrid}{%
  \symsf{H}^{\mathrm{test\mathhyphen reduction}}_{5}%
}

\begin{document}

This is ok: $\hybrid$

{\bfseries This is ok, too: $\hybrid$}

\begin{theorem}[The hybrid $\hybrid$]
The font weight of $\hybrid$ adopts to the header style.
I really like that.
But it also loads Computer Modern Bold (cmbx8) and the hyphen does not work.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

The output is

[image: Result]

The first line/paragraph is OK. The second line/paragraph uses `\bfseries` in order to switch to a bold font face. But the math is still printed in a normal weight. I deem this acceptable, too.

The theorem header contains a two-fold error:

1. Most obviously, the hyphen is missing.
2. Computer Modern is used for the superscript.

Of course, the first error is a consequence of the second error. The log file says:

```
Missing character: There is no ‐ (U+2010) in font cmbx8!
```

I do not understand what triggers the error. The command `\bfseries`, which makes the theorem header to be printed in a bold face, is also used in the second line without any problem.

How do I fix the problem?

Actually, I like the idea that the weight of the math font is adopted in the weight of the theorem header. This really makes it a visual part of the header. If there is a solution which keeps this behavior, that would be a plus. But in the first place, a solution should use the right font (Libertinus Math) and print a hyphen.

PS: This is a follow up of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528719).

---

**Addendum:**

I do not get a LaTeX error as reported by [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) in his [answer below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/528865/47156). Otherwise I would have reported that error :).

Here is the reduced log file with all version information one might need:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019 Gentoo Linux)  (format=lualatex 2020.1.1)  17 FEB 2020 19:39
 restricted system commands enabled.
**math-bold-font.tex
(./math-bold-font.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
Lua module: luaotfload-main 2019-05-18 2.97 luaotfload entry point
Lua module: luaotfload-init 2019-05-18 2.97 luaotfload submodule / initialization
Lua module: lualibs 2019-05-18 2.65 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2019-05-18 2.65 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended collection.
Lua module: luaotfload-log 2019-05-18 2.97 luaotfload submodule / logging
Lua module: luaotfload-parsers 2019-05-18 2.97 luaotfload submodule / filelist
Lua module: luaotfload-configuration 2019-05-18 2.97 luaotfload submodule / config file reader
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version “3.108”
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
File: size10.clo 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
Package: libertinus 2018/09/03 v. 0.01 (Herbert Voss) Supports libertinus fonts for pdflatex/lualatex/xelatex
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
Package: libertinus-otf 2019/04/04 v. 0.14 (Herbert Voss and Bob Tennent) Supports libertinus fonts for lualatex and xelatex.
Package: textcomp 2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX package
File: ts1enc.def 2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
Package: expl3 2019-05-09 L3 programming layer (loader) 
Package: expl3 2019-05-09 L3 programming layer (code)
Package: unicode-math 2019/03/04 v0.8o Unicode maths in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
Package: unicode-math-luatex 2019/03/04 v0.8o Unicode maths in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
Package: xparse 2019-05-03 L3 Experimental document command parser
Package: l3keys2e 2019-05-03 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
Package: fontspec 2019/03/15 v2.7c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
Package: fontenc 2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX package
Package: filehook 2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
Package: lualatex-math 2019/01/21 v1.8 Patches for mathematics typesetting with LuaLaTeX
Package: ntheorem 2011/08/15 1.33
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
```

Comment: When I try your example in texlive 2019 I get `! LaTeX Error: Math alphabet identifier \mathrm  is undefined in math version `
bold'.`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's weird, I have TexLive 2019, too. Did you run LuaLaTeX? I extend the question and post the version of all package from the log file.

Comment: I just tried it with texlive2018 and got no error (but lots and lots of warnings) perhaps you are not fully up to date with LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
 L3 programming layer <2020-02-14>

Comment: yes as I guessed you have `LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>` OK I should re-word my answer a bit to not assume that you had an error (but the fix is the same)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error because the `libertinus` loads `unicode-math` without setting a `\mathrm` font for `\mathversion{bold}`.  You can fix this with `\setboldmathrm`, from `fontspec`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertinus}
\usepackage{ntheorem}

% Enable \mathrm in \mathversion{bold}
\setboldmathrm{Libertinus Serif Bold}[Ligatures=Common, ItalicFont=Libertinus Serif Bold Italic]

% Solely to format the width of a MWE on TeX.SX:
\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm]{geometry}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newcommand*{\hybrid}{%
  \symsf{H}^{\mathrm{test\mathhyphen reduction}}_{5}%
}

\begin{document}

This is ok: $\hybrid$

{\bfseries\boldmath This is ok, too: $\hybrid$}

\begin{theorem}[The hybrid $\hybrid$]
The font weight of $\hybrid$ adapts to the header style.
I really like that.

The font is now correctly set to Libertinus Serif Bold.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image: Libertinus sample]

Comment: I wonder why you set `\mathrm` in math version bold to be Libertinus Serif Bold.  How does this interact with unicode-math? Are there any surprising side effects? Would it not be more correct to set it to Libertinus Math and tell LaTeX to use the glyphs from the range U+1D400-U+1D433 and from U+1D468-U+1D49B for bold italic, would it?

Comment: @nagmat84 no `\symbf` is designed to access the U+1D... slot bold, `\mathbf` is designed to pick up a separate bold font (in particular one with kerning and ligatures suitable for multi-letter identifiers) that's the distinction between the two commands.

Answer (score 3):

With current LaTeX, the document produces the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Math alphabet identifier \mathrm is undefined in math version bold
```

After *any* error the PDF output is not intended to be useable, just possibly an aid to debugging.

With older releases you get a lot of warnings rather than an error but the issue is essentially the same.

`ntheorem` is assuming you have `\boldmath` setup but there is no bold set up. If you add

```
  \let\boldmath\relax
```

then bold math is not used and you get no error and the fonts used in the document are:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
MMNMPW+LibertinusSerif-Regular       CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      4  0
EXEWQA+LibertinusMath-Regular        CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      5  0
ACNUSM+LibertinusSerif-Regular       CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      6  0
UJTLVL+LibertinusMath-Regular        CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      7  0
EGXLNF+LibertinusSerif-Bold          CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      8  0
NFIGQN+LibertinusSerif-Italic        CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      9  0
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not see a lot of warnings. The only warning is about the missing glyph at U+2010 for cmbx8. Also the fix does not work for me. I added `\let\boldmath\relax` even twice, in the preamble and after `\begin{document}`. The result is still the same and Latin Modern is used. I will check tomorrow, if I can update my TeX distro outside the package system of my Linux Distro. Nonetheless, it would be interesting to know what is different. It seems that my version of `ntheorem` does not rely on `\boldmath`.

Comment: @nagmat84 I tried tl2018 and an up to date tl2019,  You are using a not updated tl2019 so the exact behaviour is a bit different, but the basic issue is that it won't work, it's just a matter of where that is detected.

Comment: It’s possible to get bold math working, rather than disabling it.

Comment: @Davislor bold math is evil anyway:-) Hmm but yes I don't think I can delete this as it's accepted but if the OP moves the tick I'll delete.